# Application servers tab not enabled in Intellij ultimate edition

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, intellij-idea, application-server

So, after several years using Eclipse I finally decided to give IntelliJ a chance **(ultimate edition)**.
I added the tomcat server in the file->settings... option.
The tomcat integration plugin is also enabled in the plugin list.
Hitting Control + Shift + A and typing "Application Servers" will show me a "disabled" option. The same happens in the View menu.
So, how can I enable the tab, deploy and manage my web apps?
Thanks :)

Comment: still needs an answer

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> For this tool window to be available, the Application Servers View plugin must be enabled and there must be at least one application server run/debug configuration in your project.

Source: http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/application-servers-tool-window.html

Comment: I know this question is old, but I have the same problem. I do have the Application Server View plugin enabled and I have a run/debug config for a Spring tc server. Still no Application Server Tool window... Any other suggestions?

Comment: same here. Application servers view enabled. And there is server configured in Build Execution Deployment -> Application Servers. Still View - Tool Windows -> Application Servers disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that 'JavaEE: EJB, JPA, Servlets' plugin is enabled in intelliJ's plugins(File > Settings > Plugins['Installed' tab])